# PHP Form Builder Class - No data received

Tags: php, pfbc

I am replacing standard HTML forms with the PHP Form Builder Class (PFBC) on a legacy application that needs some TLC.

I have started the transition and converted approx. 10 pages so far, however the end users are reporting:
Often, but not always a screen that says "No data received" comes up, but when you reload the page it all works OK

I have doubled checked this and can confirm that in Chrome you get the screen that says No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

As far as I can see it's only the pages which have been converted are experiencing this and there doesn't appear to be any helpful in the server logs.

The server is running Debian 6.0.10 Squeeze with Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.3-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure this is the final correct answer, but I compared my development server with the live server and my development server had Debian 7.8 Wheezy with PHP 5.4.41

I upgraded the server to use these new versions and the problem appears to have gone away.